# Looking for a 2-way synchronization software

Tags: windows, open-source, file-synchronization, synchronization

I'm looking for a 2-way synchronization software.

I've tried WinSCP, which is a really good software but does not provide an automatic 2-way file and folder synchronization.

I've tried FullSync, which is also really good, but does not delete files : when I delete a file on a side, the file is re-created. However, for modifications and créations, it works perfectly.

I precise that is for file and folder synchronization between clients and a server. I can't install anything on the server, but what I want on the clients.

Besides, I must use the SFTP protocol.

Have you any suggestion ?

EDIT 1 : I have ommit to precise that I'm looking for a tool which can be used on Windows

EDIT 2 : I would prefer an open-source and free software, but I'm open to work with a no free software if it's a good one

EDIT 3 : I have found 'AllWay Sync', which is absolutely what I've been looking for, except that it is a paid solution (http://allwaysync.com/)

FINAL EDIT : I finally found what I was looking for and this is called FTPbox. It works almost like UpToBox, except that you control the server where datas are. If interested, go check here : http://ftpbox.org/
It's an open-source project, free, written in C# and currently maintained up-to-date. Besides, sources are downloable and you can modify it.

Comment: No experience with it on Windows, but still throwing in the keyword: you might wish to take a look at [RSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), which is available on *nix and Windows, and can be used with SSH (which corresponds to SFTP). The linked Wikipedia page also contains a [list of RSync applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#rsync_applications) for different operating systgems, including Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but RSync needs an application on the server and I can't install anything on the server...

Comment: If it's a "real server", it runs some flavor of Unix/Linux – which means RSync is already installed (which is maybe why I never noticed it needs something "on the other end", apart from SSH). Maybe you could [edit] your question and include what's running where? Obviously some Windows on the workstation (deduced from WinSCP), but you didn't specify "the other end".

Comment: My answer was deleted, but at the time I didnt have comment permissions. My answer: FreeFilesync Does work over sFtp and can do syncing both ways.

Comment: @AymericB if you are still active, can you please post the solution which you found as an answer, then wait two days and accept your own answer. That will make things easier for others in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the best solution, in my opinion, which is **FTPbox**.

It works almost like UpToBox, except that you control the server where datas are. If interested, go check here : http://ftpbox.org/

It's an open-source project, free, written in C# and currently maintained up-to-date. Besides, sources are downloable so you can modify it as you like.
Also, there is a GitHub and a Treelo where you wan participate to this project.

**Advantages :**

- Very small software
- Exist in portable version (no install needed)
- A very easy configuration
- Works over FTP and SFTP !
- Many languages
- Context menu to put files in the synchronized folder easily
- A detailed log
- Enable / Disable notifications
- Currently maintained up-to-date (in development, more functionnalities to come)
- Sync frequency is customizable !
- Absolutely free and open-source, no restrictions to use !

Have fun !

Answer (score 2):

Well, you might try [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

(I like this program a lot, but haven't used it for the purpose you are describing.)

- They tout that it can be used for file synchronization.  (You can let it 'diff' two folders, see what is not the same, and then copy things back and forth). [You can even do a three-way compare, which can be super handy].
- Apparently, you can use it for [automated synchronization](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_schedule).
- [It will work over SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640075/74817), and the software does not need to be installed at both ends.

The software is not free, but has a free trial.  It is the best software of the sort I've used, but there are many other [diffing and merging programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools), some of which may meet your needs.  I'd suggest also trying out [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) -- it should handle the SFTP requirement, too, and it is open source, but I don't think you'll find synchronizing with it to be as convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

I think it handles deletions, but am not 100% sure.  It does work on Windows, and it will work over SSH (which is close to working over SFTP).

Comment: Seems indeed a good choice (uses RSync as back-end). For details, also see [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_%28file_synchronizer%29). However, I'm afraid it conflicts with one requirement: OP writes "I can't install anything on the server" – Unison would [require exactly that](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#remote).

Comment: Unison can't handle SFTP. It works over SSH but this is a little bit different than SFTP, and I've tried right now and this is not working ...

Comment: @Izzy, oops, didn't notice that qualifier.

Comment: @AymericB that's strange. *sftp is a command-line interface client program to transfer files using the SSH File Transfer Protocol* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_file_transfer_program), that's part of OpenSSH). I'm using SFTP clients to sync files with my Linux machines over SSH, never noticed any issues. Guess your issue with Unison is rather it misses its counter-part on the server? // Clinton: Yeah, happens :)

Comment: @Izzy, Absolutely, but an  address ssh:// is different than an address sftp://, even if sftp works over ssh ...

Comment: OK, if you say so :) I've never used such a prefix. Regardless of `scp` or `sftp`, my addresses always looked like `<hostname>:/<path>`. As on CLI I've only used ssh/scp, it might well be the GUI hiding complexity. Still, I was using SFTP on one end to communicate with SSH on the other (could it be you confuse SFTP with FTPS?). But as this is [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154), let's rather discuss that in chat if needed :)

Comment: Unison can handle deletions once it has scanned both sides. If a file disappears between one scan and the next, this is considered a deletion and the file gets deleted on the other end. As for unsupported protocols and/or installing anything on the server, if you can mount the remote path (on Windows, assign a drive letter), you can synchronize it as a local folder. There is a performance penalty (as Unison will need to read everything it scans over the network rather than locally), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP now has an optional extension
[Two-Way Synchronization with Delete with SFTP/FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_two_way_synchronize_delete).

It supports two way synchronization, including synchronization of file deletions. It does that by caching a list of previous files.

As it's a script, you can customize it any way you like.